# Getting external data feeding into master/detail setup in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

Trying to get to grips with Ionic2. Can anyone see what I could be missing to get the master list of products loading? I think maybe need some sort of data query in here as well. I'm assuming my detail page should feed ok and doesn't need any extra imports, just the NavParams get request.

Here is the Github repo I have setup https://github.com/jones98/Ion2Blank

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import { DetailPage } from '../pages/detail/detail';
import { Sheetsu } from '../../providers/sheetsu';

/*
  Generated class for the Master page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-master',
  templateUrl: 'master.html',
  providers: [Sheetsu]
})
export class MasterPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public sheetsuService: Sheetsu) {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.sheetsuService.getRemoteData();
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad MasterPage');
  }

  itemTapped(event, data) {
    this.navCtrl.push(DetailPage, {
      data: data
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Well your code looks correct, could reduce future code by moving Sheetsu to ngModel's providers. Then, your `sheetsu.getRemoteData()` just `console.log`'s your data. (isn't what you want I think) so on your MasterPage you're currently unable to print your remoteData

Comment: Please elaborate further on the actual problem you're encountering

Comment: This is the current error on build - goo.gl/2qawFS But I haven't been able to get a list of products in master using *ngFor which should load the products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok couple of things, first of all your import is wrong, if you have a package structure like the following

```
|
-pages
|
--master
|      |
|      -- master.ts
|
-- detail
|      |
|      -- detail.ts
.....
```

And from `master.ts` you're calling `import { Detail } from '../pages/detail/detail'`, the `..` will jump 1 directory back (current: master), jumping to `./pages`. Now you're searching for a directory called `pages` within a directory called `pages`, thus searching for `pages/pages/detail/detail` which doesn't exist. Changing your import to `../../pages/detail/detail` or `../detail/detail` would work.

Second your `getRemoteData()` doesn't return anything. Change the method to the one matching below

```
getRemoteData(): any{
      return this.http.get('https://sheetsu.com/apis/v1.0/d0b1d8ecfc4f')
               .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Then, in your `master.ts` you can retrieve the data actually returned from this api by calling:

```
export class MasterPage {

  // declare publicly accessible variable
  public sheetsuData: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public sheetsuService: Sheetsu) {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.sheetsuService.getRemoteData()
     .subscribe(response => {
       // assign variable (async)
       this.sheetsuData = response;
     });
  }

  itemTapped(event, data) {
    this.navCtrl.push(DetailPage, {
      data: data
    });
  }

}
```

And then having an html file containing something like this

```
<div *ngFor="let sheetsu of sheetsuData" (click)="itemTapped($event, sheetsu)">
  {{sheetsu}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou for taking the time to help, its looking alot better now. Much appreciated, ticked.

Comment: No problem, if you run into any other problem, just ask another question/message me, I'm quite active on the [ionic2] tag, so are a couple of others

Comment: Thankyou almost there, the master is loading (sort of) but the detail page is displaying fine. Here is the app in action https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3ArIuPt8mKRVFNkWWJfT1JhLUE/view and a screenshot of the DOM https://s27.postimg.org/6s2d9gx2b/master_missing.jpg ,something is blocking the name from showing? GitHub should be up to date with the code causing this.

Comment: Ah, you're trying `<p>{{ product_name }}</p>` when `product_name` is a property of the objects in your list. Since you iterate over your list and assign the name `sheetsu` to the current object of the list, try `<p>{{sheetsu.product_name}}</p>`

Comment: Awesome! Thats done it,brilliant. Strangely the detail page had {data.apple_cat}} that loaded fine after the data was fed through. Anyway, all good :-)

Comment: Yes that makes sense, you're pushing the entire object in your parameters and naming it 'data' when you're doing `push(Detail, {data: data})`

Comment: So in your detail page you probably have `this.data = navParama.get('data');`